# "grep" with column value and attach new column bash / awk /grep?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I have unique action to do. I have these two files:

file1:

```
something SOME.THING-AGAIN-WHATEVER.SUPPORT irrelevant_column3_text
```

file2:

```
SOMETHING-NEW-SOME-THING-AGAIN-WHATEVER-SUPPORT
```

Column 2 from file1 (SOME.THING....)
is very similar to column in filre2 (SOMETHING...), except that:
- it has dots instead of dashes
- it misses some parts of a text from the beggining and the end.

What I want to get is this:

```
something SOME.THING-AGAIN-WHATEVER.SUPPORT irrelevant_column3_text SOMETHING-NEW-SOME-THING-AGAIN-WHATEVER-SUPPORT
```

So four column file, with attached in correct place input from file2...

I assume that this can be done using awk, but this is definitely beyond my skills...
thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Well, you didn't shown what you've tried. Do it like this: for each line in file1 get the value of the second column. Then remove the dots from the column and search for such value in file2. If you found it, append it to the line. Alternatively you can create a file3 from the file1 second column and even use join to merge the files.

Comment: Read up on `cut` and `paste`. It might take a few steps if you're new, but you can get it done.

Comment: Paul if that would be matter of copy and paste I wouldn't put it here...I do not understand why you are so unpleasant...

@Kamil, I was thinking of what you have suggested, but the problem comes here: "Remove the dots from the column and search"...OK I can easily do it with - for example - sed and with "echo -n" I can have columns from those files next to each other, but HOW will I "return" to the dashes instead of dots? 
What I am trying to say is that, the way you have described I will "damaging" file1's column. How can I overcome that?

Comment: @IrkaIrenka - with that extremely limited dataset and a sample of one it would be impossible to come up with a robust solution; this requires a step of pre-processing of either the values in column 2 of file1 or of file2. Even if this wasn't off-topic as kvantour pointed out, the question would be to vague to deal with.

Comment: OK I understand, will try to make my post better next time. Sorry for not following the rules of the forum.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achive what I've wanted with simple grep and echo :)

```
for i in $(file1 ); do echo -n "$i " ; grep $(echo $i|awk '{print $1}' |sed s'/\./-/g') file2;done
```

Hope that helps to someone.